# What does this chart denote?

Tags: self-study, data-visualization, trend

[image]

I am trying to plot the total number of accidents in each month when there is some precipitation recorded and total number of accidents in each month when there was low visibility using a multi line chart. This I am using to compare the trends in each type of accidents in each. But I a not able to comprehend much from this chart.

Can anyone please suggest me what type of analysis is in this chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is pretty explicit.  It is a time series over a 12 month period (X-Axis) that plots the number of weather related crashes that can range from 0 to 4500 in anyone month (Y-Axis).  And, it shows that the number of visibility-related crashes are very low ranging from 0 to close to 1,000 (in the 5 month).  Meanwhile, the precipitation-related crashes are a lot more numerous ranging from a minimum of 2,000 in the 3d month to 4,500 in the 12 month.  What is interesting is that the two trends over time seem to be pretty correlated.  You could also construct a scatter plot with one type of accident on one axis and the other on the other axis.  And, I am pretty sure you would see a very strong linear relationship between the two.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by correlated?

Comment: Two variables are positively correlated if they move somewhat together in the same direction.  With time series such as the ones you are dealing with, when precipitation-related crashes go up so does visibility-related crashes.  And, when one goes down, the other tends to go down to.  That's positive correlation.  As a side note, if you gave me best answer, it is standard to give one an up vote.